# Why doesn't Spring JPA add quote around the escape character when used with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I recently migrated my code from Spring boot 2.7 to Spring boot 3.1 and I encounter a problem on a specific method for a Spring Data JPA Repository used to search a specific user by name in my database.

Here is the code (in kotlin) :

```kotlin
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<UserEntity, String>{

   fun findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrNameContainingIgnoreCase(
        firstNameSearchTerm: String,
        nameSearchTerm: String,
    ): List<UserEntity>
```

Here is the SQL generated :

```
select
    u1_0.id,
    u1_0.first_name,
    u1_0.name
from
    users u1_0
where upper(u1_0.first_name) like upper(?) escape \
or upper(u1_0.name) like upper(?) escape \
```

and here is the error :

```
2023-10-02T12:16:06.997+02:00  WARN 98232 --- [nio-9595-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-10-02T12:16:07.310+02:00 ERROR 98232 --- [nio-9595-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
```

If a copy the code and try to execute it in my client, I got the same kind of error. I can fix it by putting the `\`character between quote, like this.

```
select
    u1_0.id,
    u1_0.first_name,
    u1_0.name
from
    users u1_0
where upper(u1_0.first_name) like upper(?) escape '\'
or upper(u1_0.name) like upper(?) escape '\'
```

I have a whole bunch of workaround, but I would like to know if there is a configuration somebody that I missed, because I would very like avoid to have this error creep around and get back on a repository method only used for a forgotten edge case :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: That doesn't look like sql that would be accepted by postgres

Comment: That's exactly my problem. :)
If you are speaking about the "working" SQL, my client (Intellij Database console) ask for the value to use instead of the `?`character before executing it, if this is what bothering you.

Comment: Yes, the `?` parameter is what I was wondering about.

Comment: It's used for indicated a statement parameter. I keep like it because Hibernate use it for logging SQL query, for security reason I imagine.
But If you replace it by a valid value (for example `'%fra%'` and try to execute it, you will see that the problem reside in the incorrect use of the `\`character. And I dont know why JPA mess up the query like that.

Comment: It is Hibernate that is actually generating the query not Spring Data JPA. So I would see what the query was when generated with Spring Boot 2.7 and compare it with Spring BOot 3. Hibernate did change a lot of things (internally and around query generation) so I suspect this is some kind of regression.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. And it was neither linked to Spring or Hibernate.

I had a dependency to `io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.0` in my code. Upgrading this dependency to the latest minor version `3.5.2` fixed the problem

For the record, it manifested only when using the Spring data `Containing` (or alternative) keyword.